# How to delete strings of a variable, if after check it in array, it's not match with array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

How can I remove instances of words from a string which do not appear in an array?

```
$myVar = "my sisteralannis is not that blonde, here is a goodplace";
$myWords=array(
    array("is","é"),
    array("on","no"),
    array("that","aquela"),
    array("sister","irmã"), 
    array("my","minha"),
    array("myth","mito"),
    array("not","não"),
    array("he","ele"),
    array("good","bom"),
    array("place","lugar"),
    array("here","aqui"),
    array("ace","perito")
); 

echo $myVar;
```

The strings `'sisteralannis'` and `'goodplace'` do not exists in the `$myWords` array and should be removed from the string.

**Expected Output:** `my is not that, here is`

Comment: @mickmickusa , is much simpler now, just removing of the variable the strings that do not exist in the array, solve my problem.

Comment: why u dont combine all array to one 2d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to explode that variable, and check in a loop if they match.
Try this example:

```php
$myVar = "my sisteralannis is not that blonde, here is a goodplace";

$myWords=array(
        array("is","é"),
        array("on","no"),
        array("that","aquela"),
        array("sister","irmã"), 
        array("my","minha"),
        array("myth","mito"),
        array("not","não"),
        array("he","ele"),
        array("good","bom"),
        array("place","lugar"),
        array("here","aqui"),
        array("ace","perito")
    );

$words = explode(" ",$myVar);

foreach($myWords as $w){
    $words = array_diff($words,$w);
}

$words = array_diff(explode(" ",$myVar),$words);

echo implode(" ",$words);
```

Output:

```
my is not that here is
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @EL3PHANTEN, but it lacks a small adjustment, its code mixes the order of the strings in the output: `is that my not here`

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego oh yes ofc. Fixed it :) and a bit cleaner

Comment: Thank you very much, it really was very good, it works in first attempt on my project too. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego You are wellcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below. Ive added a function inspect_data() to trim the data, and ive added a function called exclude_characters() to consider the characters that you dont want to be included on your data comparison.

```html
<?php 

function inspect_data($text, $array){
    $data = '';
    foreach($array as $myWord){
        if(in_array($text,$myWord)){            
            $data=$text;
        }

    }
    return $data;
}

function exclude_characters($text){

    $excluded_characters = array(',','!');

    $data['string'] = '';
    $data['special'] = '';
    foreach($excluded_characters as $char){
        if (strpos($text, $char) !== false) {
            $data['string'] = str_replace($char,"",$text);
            $data['special'] = $char;
        }
        else{
             $data['string'] = $text;
          
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

$myVar = "my sisteralannis is not that blonde, here is a goodplace";
    $myWords=array(
        array("is","é"),
        array("on","no"),
        array("that","aquela"),
        array("sister","irmã"), 
        array("my","minha"),
        array("myth","mito"),
        array("not","não"),
        array("he","ele"),
        array("good","bom"),
        array("place","lugar"),
        array("here","aqui"),
        array("ace","perito")
    ); 

$newVar = '';
$var = explode(" ",$myVar);
foreach($var as $v){
    
    $data = exclude_characters($v);
    $newVar .= inspect_data($data['string'],$myWords).$data['special']." ";
    
}
echo $newVar;






 ?>
```